# All the lamps in my house won’t work

Tags: light-fixture, lamp

So the other day I bought a cheap lamp. Plugged it in etc and the bulb blew straight away. After that my other lamp stopped working (which was plugged into the same socket).  Changed the lightbulbs etc in both, still not working. Checked my electrics in case anything had tripped and that’s all sorted. Changed the fuse in my old lamp (not the new cheap one as that is being returned). Still not working. Figured the cheap one has somehow destroyed my older one. Bought a brand new lamp today, will not work. Also spent loads of money on new lightbulbs. Not working. Tried other appliances in the same sockets and they work fine. If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it as I am at my wits end. Thanks in advance guys

Hi guys, thanks for already starting to help. We are in the UK and the electrics box, I just checked all the switches. In my old house, if a specific area tripped then that switch would go down and I’d just flick it back. This house though, that doesn’t happen. So I did it myself; flicked them off and then back up. Sorry, I really don’t know technical words at all –

Comment: What country are you located in?  And “in case anything tripped and that’s all sorted.”  Can you please be more specific about any actions taken there.

Comment: @Tyson "Changed the fuse in my old lamp" *suggests* the UK (I can't think of any other country where plug-in lamps have fuses.  But Victoria, please [edit] your question to confirm (or deny) that.

Comment: Also, what sort of lamps were these?

Comment: @MartinBonner that was my likely guess too! But I asked because it was only a guess.  Another reason for putting the question out there is because a huge number of people read with only USA in mind, and start making suggestions that may not apply in this case.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for already starting to help. We are in the UK and the electrics box, I just checked all the switches. In my old house, if a specific area tripped then that switch would go down and I’d just flick it back. This house though, that doesn’t happen. So I did it myself; flicked them off and then back up. Sorry, I really don’t know technical words at all